# Can someone check my answer to this question about approximating a function with a polynomial

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, polynomials

Let $f\in C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$. The n-th moment of f is defined to be $M_n=\int_0^1f(x)x^n\;dx,\;n\geq0.$ Show that if $M_n=0$, for all $n\geq 0$, then $f=0$.

My answer;

By the Weierstrass approximation theorem there exists a polynomial p st $||f-p||_{\infty}\leq \epsilon$ for any positive $\epsilon$. Note we have that for any polynomial q $\int_0^1 f(x)q(x) \; dx =0$. Now;

$p(x)-\epsilon \leq f(x) \leq p(x)+\epsilon$ so

$0\leq f(x)^2 \leq max(p(x)f(x)-\epsilon f(x), p(x)f(x)+\epsilon f(x))$ (*) so

$0 \leq f(x)^2 \leq p(x)f(x) + max(-\epsilon f(x), \epsilon f(x))$ (**) so

$0 \leq f(x)^2 \leq p(x)f(x)+\epsilon |f(x)|$

then the answer follows easily but basically all I wanted to check was going from (*) to (**) was a valid step, sorry if it seems like a dumb question but I just want to be sure. Also I know there is a quicker more elegant way to do this because I've looked at the answer. Thanks

Comment: Got something from the answer?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, for every real numbers $u$ and $v$, $$\max(u+v,u-v)=u+\max(v,-v)=u+|v|.$$

Comment: Interesting and nice equalities. Pretty easy to prove, but I never thought of this. +1